# Selecting data from ajax responded div using jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am working on making hashtag system based on codeigniter  for that i need to select data from ajax returned value which work based on input given through text box i tried to alert the value from jquery but alert box has no value or empty

controller upload has function hastag

```
public function hashTag()
{
    $test = $this->input->post('search');
    echo $test;
}





<div class="form-group col-sm-9">
                  <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" 
                            id="inputPjctTag" name="pjctTag" placeholder="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6" id="display">
                </div>
            </div>
```

javascript is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( "#inputPjctTag" ).keypress(function() {
        $.ajax({url: "http://localhost/ci/upload/hashTag",data:'search='+$("#inputPjctTag").val(),type:"POST", success: function(result){
                        $('#display').html(result);
                        $('#inputPjctTag').prepend(result);
                    }});
    });
    $( "#display" ).click(function() {
        var resul = $('#display').val();
        alert(resul);
        $("#inputPjctTag").prepend(data)
    });

</script>
```

i dont know what is wrong please help me

Comment: `#display` is a `div` and `div` doesn't have any value... you should use `$('#display').text()` or `$('#display').html()`

Comment: Yes it Worked expected result is obtained

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `div` tag never has a value as it has only `text` and `html`.

```
 $( "#display" ).click(function() {
    var resul = $('#display').val();
    alert(resul);
    $("#inputPjctTag").prepend(data)
});
```

Change it with this:

```
 $( "#display" ).click(function() {
    var resul = $('#display').text(); //Or $('#display').html() for html
    alert(resul);
    $("#inputPjctTag").prepend(data)
});
```

Comment: any suggestion for implementing hastagging

Comment: Do you want hashtags in your url?

Comment: i completed hastag system using your help tnks @Poonam

Answer (score 0):

take this

```
    public function hashTag()
    {
    //$test = $this->input->post('search');
    echo "hashTAG";
    }
```

what you get in alert? if you get above means post is not happening.

Comment: i get same result empty alert box

Comment: which means post is not happening, verify why so.

Comment: Hi bro Problem is resolved few days back using above answer given by poonam but i really respect and thankful for your kind time